# Are there ready solutions for saving robot framework test results into a database?

Tags: test-management, database, robotframework

I like the level of details and more or less how they look like — report.html and log.html files created as a result of selenium/robot tests run. What I don't like is if I run pybot several times (with different tags for example) these files gets rewritten, and I loose previous run results unless I'm running all of them as a predefined set.

I thought it would be nice to store test runs results in a database.

Are there any ready or obvious solutions for that easier than to fire up a django site to handle all that? I want to be able to see a list of available last few hours/days results and click and see details the same way I can dig in now from report.html into log.html down to the individual steps. Would be nice if it'll support multiple users + continuos integration writing results into the same database. Being able to see results from various hosts through a browser without ssh-ing into these machines seems important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent overwriting the earlier results, you can specify where you want the logs and results with command line options --output, --log (-l) and --report (-r). There is also an option --timestampoutputs (-T) for automatically timestamping the result files to get output-20080604-163225.xml or similar.

There seems to be at least two database libraries [Robotframework-Database-Library](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/) and [robotframework-dblibrary](https://github.com/ThomasJaspers/robotframework-dblibrary). I haven't used either so unfortunately I can't comment on them.

Answer (score 2):

As a previous answer stated, it is possible to save the test output as XML (output.xml) but to put the results into a database, you would have to create a parser and table structure to handle all that.

If you are just wanting to have the test results stored in a central place then I would recommend setting up Jenkins and running your Robot Framework tests from there. Loading the Robot Framework plugin adds some really nice reporting functionality: how the test results differed from the previous result, if tests were added or removed, how long a test has been failing; see the link below: 
(see "Detailed Build view" screenshot)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

For a pre-built solution you might want to look at [DbBot](https://github.com/robotframework/DbBot).

For a custom solution you can use the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-listener-interface) to robot framework. It's pretty easy to write a listener that writes a record to a database every time a keyword, test case or test suite finishes running.

My team created a little web service for this, but you can just as easily open a direct connection to your database from the listener and store the results directly.

Answer (score -1):

On a Linux machine, you can direct Pybot to save log files to a different 
folder which is time-stamped:

```
-d results/result-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S)
```

Comment: Welcome to SQA Stack Exchange. We prefer longer answers with more explanation - please edit your answer to explain how piping to a directory on the local system would help with viewing results through a browser and being able to view results from multiple hosts.